# Possible for Control to Span Half ColumnSpan in Grid?

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid, columnspan

Like the title says, is it possible for a control to span half of a column?
I get the following error when I try:

```
<Button Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1.5"/>

Cannot convert string '1.5' in attribute 'ColumnSpan' to object of type 'System.Int32'. 1.5 is not a valid value for Int32
```

EDIT: I understand that, using this method, it is not possible. I'm asking if there is another way for a control to visibly span a column and a half.

Thanks!

Comment: The error message is clear: No you can't.

Comment: Is there an alternate solution you can recommend?

Comment: I can't tell what you want to do here. But Grid-in-Grid can solve a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I'll look into it!

Answer (score 4):

Divide the column into 2 equal columns and then span the 1st one. 
That's the only possible way to achieve what you need.